# How to create navbar dropdown that clickable on mobile and hover to open on desktop

Tags: html, css, frontend, navbar, bootstrap-5

I am using Bootstrap 5 to create a website. I am trying to use Bootstrap 5 to create a navbar dropdown. Currently when you are on mobile and you click the dropdown it opens but when you click it again it doesn't close. when you are on desktop if you hover over it, it opens and closes properly, however, if you are on desktop and you click on the dropdown instead of hovering over it and you move your cursor off the dropdown menu the dropdown menu turns white.

### This is it what it looks like [image]

```css
@import "./.fonts.css";
:root {
  --desktop: 1200px;
  --laptop: 992px;
  --tablet: 768px;
  --mobile: 576px;
}

body {
  background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#copyright {
  border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
}

.c-item {
  height: 900px;
}

.c-img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}

h3:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
  bottom: -10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

#sub-header {
  color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#navbar-color {
  background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  border: 1px solid white;
}


/* @media (min-width: 576px) {
    
} */

footer a i {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


/* SMALL MEDIA QUERY */


/* @media screen and (min-width: var(--mobile)) and (max-width: var(--tablet)) { */

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 175px;
  .btn {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  }
  .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
  }
}

footer li:hover {
  color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

footer i:hover {
  color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
  transition: 0.2s;
}


/* @media (min-width: 576px) {
        .nav-link::after {
            content: '';
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.2s;
            height: 2px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        
        .nav-link:hover::after {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }
    } */


}
#nav_object {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  /* text-decoration: underline; */
  /* border-bottom: 2px solid  hsl(18, 100%, 62%); */
}
#nav_object::after {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#nav_object:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-item a {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
    color: white !important;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false" id="">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
          // Get the Services dropdown link element
          const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
        
          // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
          servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
          });
        
          // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
          if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
            // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
            });
        
            // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
            });
          }
        </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION START -->
    
        <!-- <button 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary" 
          data-bs-toggle="modal" 
          data-bs-target="#loginmodal"
        >
          Login/Signup
        </button>
        <div id="loginmodal" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <button
                 
                  type="button" 
                  class="btn-close btn-close-white" 
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
                ></button>
                <div class="myform bg-dark">
                  <h1 class="text-center" id="modal-styling">Login Form</h1>
                  <form action="#">
                    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="passeord" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mt-3">LOGIN</button>
                    <p id="modal-styling">Don't have an account? <a href="#" id="modal-styling">Signup</a> </p>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> -->
    <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION CLOSE -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->




   
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce what happens in your screenshot.  However when I hover over an item in the dropdown that does have a white background. If you inspect the element with broser devtools it shows that the white background is caused by this line in the bootstrap CSS `background-color: var(--bs-dropdown-link-hover-bg);`

So we just have to override that CSS variable like this:

```css
.dropdown-menu{
  --bs-dropdown-link-hover-bg: hsl(210, 55%, 41%) !important;
}
```

and that's all.  I've done this and commented out some other CSS you have where you tried to set this color which you no longer need.

```css
@import "./.fonts.css";
:root {
  --desktop: 1200px;
  --laptop: 992px;
  --tablet: 768px;
  --mobile: 576px;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  --bs-dropdown-link-hover-bg: hsl(210, 55%, 41%) !important;
}

body {
  background: hsl(233, 47%, 96%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#copyright {
  border-top: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
}

.c-item {
  height: 900px;
}

.c-img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.6);
}

#team-img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

/*
.dropdown-item:hover {
  background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
}
*/


h3:after {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
  bottom: -10px;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
}

#sub-header {
  color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
}

#navbar-color {
  background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler-icon {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%28255, 255, 255, 1%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.navbar-light .navbar-toggler {
  border: 1px solid white;
}


/* @media (min-width: 576px) {
    
} */

footer a i {
  color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}


/* SMALL MEDIA QUERY */


/* @media screen and (min-width: var(--mobile)) and (max-width: var(--tablet)) { */

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: hsl(210, 45%, 30%);
  margin-top: 0;
  width: 175px;
  .btn {
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  }
  /*
  .dropdown-item:hover {
    background-color: hsl(210, 55%, 41%);
  }
  */
}

footer li:hover {
  color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

footer i:hover {
  color: hsl(24, 83%, 65%);
  transition: 0.2s;
}


/* @media (min-width: 576px) {
        .nav-link::after {
            content: '';
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.2s;
            height: 2px;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        
        .nav-link:hover::after {
            opacity: 1;
            transition: all 0.2s;
        }
    } */


}
#nav_object {
  position: relative;
}
.nav-link:hover {
  /* text-decoration: underline; */
  /* border-bottom: 2px solid  hsl(18, 100%, 62%); */
}
#nav_object::after {
  content: '';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: hsl(18, 100%, 62%);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#nav_object:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.nav-item a {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
    color: white !important;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

<title>Home | </title>

<!-- <meta name="description" content="Write an awesome description for your new site here. It will appear in your document head meta (for Google search results) and in your feed.xml site description." /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_bridgetown/static/css/main.c7d4dd3f1984a290e9be.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/dropdown.css" />
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/login-modal.css"> -->
<link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Default"
    disabled
          href="/css/app-937c1ff7d52fd6f78dd9322599e2b5d4.css?vsn=d"
        >
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          data-purpose="Layout StyleSheet"
          title="Web Awesome"

          href="/css/app-wa-8d95b745961f6b33ab3aa1b98a45291a.css?vsn=d"
        >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/all.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-solid.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-regular.css"
          >

          <link
            rel="stylesheet"

            href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/css/sharp-light.css"
          >
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Bootstrap-/images/favicon-32x32.png">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR START -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light py-3 sticky-top" id="navbar-color">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html">
          <img src="./src/img/logo-topnav.png" height="45" width="225" class="img-fluid"/>
        </a>

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
        <button
          type="button"
          class="navbar-toggler"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navmenu"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
        </button>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- TOGGLE MENU START -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/index.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/about.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">About</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown"  aria-expanded="false" id="">
          Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <!-- <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li> -->
          <!-- <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li> -->
          <li><a class="dropdown-item   text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/cctv.html">CCTV Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/datacenter.html">Datacenter Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/digital-signage.html">Digital Signage</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="/Bootstrap-/gen-support.html">General Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/net-support.html">Network Support</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/pos.html">POS Services</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item text-white " href="/Bootstrap-/telecom.html">Telecom Services</a></li>
          
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a href="/Bootstrap-/contact.html" class="nav-link text-white" id="nav_object">Contact</a></li>

        <script>
          // Get the Services dropdown link element
          const servicesDropdown = document.getElementById('servicesDropdown');
        
          // Redirect to the services page when the dropdown link is clicked
          servicesDropdown.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default link behavior
            window.location.href = this.getAttribute('href');
          });
        
          // Add the hover effect on desktop devices
          if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 576px)').matches) {
            // When the mouse enters the dropdown link, show the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.add('show');
            });
        
            // When the mouse leaves the dropdown link or the dropdown menu, hide the dropdown menu
            servicesDropdown.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
              this.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
              this.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('show');
            });
          }
        </script>
        <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->

        <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION START -->
    
        <!-- <button 
          type="button" 
          class="btn btn-primary" 
          data-bs-toggle="modal" 
          data-bs-target="#loginmodal"
        >
          Login/Signup
        </button>
        <div id="loginmodal" class="modal fade">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <button
                 
                  type="button" 
                  class="btn-close btn-close-white" 
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
                ></button>
                <div class="myform bg-dark">
                  <h1 class="text-center" id="modal-styling">Login Form</h1>
                  <form action="#">
                    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="passeord" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mt-3">LOGIN</button>
                    <p id="modal-styling">Don't have an account? <a href="#" id="modal-styling">Signup</a> </p>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> -->
    <!-- LOGIN/SIGNUP MODAL SECTION CLOSE -->
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- TOGGLE MENU CLOSE -->
      </div>
    
    </nav>
    <!-- NAVIGATION BAR CLOSE -->




   
  </body>
</html>
```